# JSON.parse error 785 unexpected token error

Tags: json, ruby

I am trying to parse JSON data in my Rails 5 application with JSON.parse. I keep getting this error:

```
"#<JSON::ParserError: 785: unexpected token at ': Hours,\n  \"config\": {\n    \"blocks\": <\n      {\n        \"type\": table,\n        \"name\": Hours from Users,\n        \"fields\": [\n          \"customer\",\n          \"project\",\n          \"user\",\n          \"task\",\n          \"hour_type\",\n          \"amount\"\n        ]\n      }\n    >\n  }>"
```

Comment: Starts with ': Hours' is not a legitimate json.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is how can i solve this error?

Comment: That string doesn't contain valid JSON and therefore cannot be parsed. Who to solve? Depends on where you got the string from? Did you build it? That fix how you build the JSON and build valid JSON. Did someone send you that string? Then ask that person if the string is actually intended to be JSON or something else.

Answer (score 2):

here is what it looks like if you print the message:

```
#<JSON::ParserError: 785: unexpected token at ': Hours,
  "config": {
    "blocks": <
      {
        "type": table,
        "name": Hours from Users,
        "fields": [
          "customer",
          "project",
          "user",
          "task",
          "hour_type",
          "amount"
        ]
      }
    >
  }>
```

you forgot to quote certain values like `table` and `Hours from Users`, they need double-quotes `"` to be valid json.

(also not sure about the extra `<` and `>`, might be coming from the parser error)

Answer (score 1):

Change from `:json` to `:hybrid` like:

```
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.cookies_serializer = :hybrid
```

as explained [in this Rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33580):